# How can i cancel the subscriber?

Tags: ios

```
@weakify(self)
[[self.listModel.firstLoadCommand execute:nil] subscribeNext:^(NSNumber *nType) {


    @strongify(self)
    [HUDManager removeHUDFromView:self.view];

    self.isFirstRequest = NO;

    NSInteger pageIndex = nType.integerValue;
    //Select some page
    [self.listTabBar selectTabBarAtIndex:pageIndex ];


} error:^(NSError *error)
 {
     @strongify(self)

     self.isFirstRequest = NO;

     [HUDManager removeHUDFromView:self.view];

     JKBaseSearchViewController *viewController = [_pageArray objectOrNilAtIndex:0];

     [HUDManager showNonNetWorkHUDInView:viewController.view];

 }];
```

now,
  I use the signal send a request, but the network service is not active,
i  find the controller wait a minute free, i want  when i pop this controller,it's free! how solve this problem ?  thanks!!

Comment: I want when i pop controller ,the controller can free!

Comment: and also，can i bind a parameter to Singleton's parameter?